# Random Servlet UnavailableException

Tags: exception, websphere, servletexception

My application is trying to connect to a third party website (url) and sometimes I get the **javax.servlet.UnavailableException**. If I try to connect again (click submit button), then it works. If I click submit again, it may or may not work. So it is inconsistent. The application is deployed in WebSphere.

The error message is:

**Error page exception**
The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below. Please see the Error Page Exception below for a description of the problem with the specified error page.

**Original Exception:** 
Error Message: 
Error Code: 404
Target Servlet: action
Error Stack: 
javax.servlet.UnavailableException 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:361) 
     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3673) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831) 
     at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478) 
     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:457) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:300) 
     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:271) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113) 
     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751) 
     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881) 
     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1593)

Is it a config issue or issue with my code or the 3rd party website?

Comment: It *sounds* like an uncaught exception in your application. That is, when it gets an exception communicating with that 3rd-party site, it doesn't catch and report it nicely, but simply lets it pass back up to WebSphere. Which is in turn throwing that generic exception.

Comment: Fixed the issue, it was server down on the 3rd party site, now its working fine.